# Can 'sed' do 'or' class trimming?

Tags: linux, sed

I am working with a piece of code but it's ugly. It has a nasty line in it along the lines of:

```
s/COM/ALPHA BETA GAMMA COM/g
s/DLX/ALPHA BETA GAMMA DLX/g
s/BE4/ALPHA BETA GAMMA BE4/g
s/BE2/ALPHA BETA GAMMA BE2/g
s/RS/ALPHA BETA GAMMA RS/g
```

If any of `BE2`, `RS`, etc. are found then it will replaced with `Alpha Beta Gamma COM/DLX/BE4/BE2/RS`. However, if all three are found then each one will be replaced. Since the ideal output would be:

```
ALPHA BETA GAMMA COM DLX BE4 BE2 RS
```

is there anyway to code this in sed please? It is truly "either NED or JED or TED." Alternatively, can other Linux be used?

Comment: Please post sample input and expected sample output in your post too.

Comment: Do you mean you need [`s/[NTJ]ED/ALPHA BETA GAMMA &/g`](https://ideone.com/wyS1qZ)?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that - I made a poor choice of names. I'm afraid not, the true values are COM, DLX, BE4, BE2 and RS. I thought Ned and Ted would be easier to follow.

Comment: @HugMyster, it's always advisable to post samples in your post not on comments, so please do so.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I'm trying to find some...

Comment: You've shown us the expected output but still not the input that you;d get that output from running the desired tool on. Please add the missing sample input to your question, Also, you've told us what happens if 1 is found, and what happens if 3 are found but you haven't told us what happens if 2 are found so add that info to your question too.

Comment: I put all the details from comments to the question itself, since the original wording misled everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you want to prepend a line having any of the alternatives you listed with `ALPHA BETA GAMMA`.

You may use

```
echo "COM, DLX, BE4, BE2 and RS" | sed -E 's/.*\<(COM|DLX|BE4|BE2|RS)\>/ALPHA BETA GAMMA &/'
# => ALPHA BETA GAMMA COM, DLX, BE4, BE2 and RS
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/QPqf2Q).

**Details**

- `-E` - a POSIX ERE enabling option
- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `\<` - leading word boundary
- `(COM|DLX|BE4|BE2|RS)` - matches `COM` or `DLX` or `BE4` or `BE2` or `RS`
- `\>` - trailing word boundary
- `ALPHA BETA GAMMA &` - replace with `ALPHA BETA GAMMA`, space and the *whole match value* (`&`).

Comment: This looks promising, except that for an input of COM and DLX, I would like an output of "ALPHA BETA GAMMA COM DLX". It is when the input has no entries, such as "MV", that the output should simply be "MV".

Comment: @HugMyster So, you have `COM and DLX` string? Do you mean you only want to perform a single replacement? Remove `g` - see [`echo "COM and DLX" | sed -E 's/COM|DLX|BE4|BE2|RS/ALPHA BETA GAMMA &/'`](https://ideone.com/jFw4kI).

Comment: One string for them all, yes. I'm trying to get a sample but they tend to be massive.

Comment: Now THAT looks useful! Please just give me a minute to pipe it through...

Comment: @HugMyster Probably, you also want to match them as whole words, wrap with `\<(...)\>`. I updated the solution so that it fully answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.
With the input file.txt:

```
NED one
two TED
3 JED 4
```

You can do this:

```
sed 's/NED\|TED\|JED/ALPHA BETA GAMMA &/g' file.txt
ALPHA BETA GAMMA NED one
two ALPHA BETA GAMMA TED
3 ALPHA BETA GAMMA JED 4
```